# C# - Implementing virtual void 2 levels down?

Tags: c#

Consider this example.

We have a class called Control. Then we have a class inheriting that class, called CollectionControl. Finally, on top of all this, we have a class called ListBox that inherits CollectionControl.

Now, let's say that Control has a method called "OnSizeChanged", which is defined the following way:

```
    internal protected virtual void OnSizeChanged(Vector size)
    {
    }
```

How would I override this method from ListBox?

If I can't, what would be the best work-around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `override` keyword as usual. No special incantations are required for once-removed inheritance relationships.

Comment: Wow, I see. Visual Studio 2010 intellisense just wasn't showing up for that particular thing.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, "internal protected" means that it's visible to EITHER a derived class OR another class in the assembly.

So if you wanted to override it in a derived class, you could do something like this:

```
protected override void OnSizeChanged(Vector size)
```

Here is a good link:

http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/lesson19.aspx